# Jquery image load order

Tags: jquery, image

I have a site with many large images, and I want to delay their loading until after the smaller UI graphics have loaded.  I used html like this:

```
 <span id="img0" class="preload" data-src="/images/tomato.jpg"></span>
 <span id="img1" class="preload" data-src="/images/squash.jpg"></span>
```

I thought that I could collect all instances of class "preload", and then order them by ID, and then add in the html which calls the image.

The problem is that it's just loading the same image each time.

Here is the **Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/nUFUW/

---

**ANSWER**: (Html as above).  To load images in the order of their IDs and also have html that will validate:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".preload").each(loadImages);

        function loadImages (i, elem) {

            var numItems = $('.preload').length;
            for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {

                $("#img" + i).each(function(){
                    var thisSource = $(this).data('src');
                    $(this).html('<img src="' + thisSource + '" alt=""/>');
                });
            }

    } //<end loadImages function>

});
```

Note that any images in the page which you haven't replaced with Span tags will load before those that are Spans.  I guess that's because it's all happening before 'document ready" fires.  Thus it wasn't necessary to tag each image in the UI, only the large ones.  Now my large images load last, which is how I like it.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {

    function loadImage(i){
        if($("#img" + i).size() == 0)
            return;
        $("#img" + i).load(function(){
            loadImage(i + 1);
        });
        $("#img" + i).attr('src', $("#img" + i).data("src"));
    }
    loadImage(0);

});
```

​
    ​

Comment: Won't this just load them in the order they are in the page, rather than loading them in order of ID?

Comment: sorry, I forgot about the ordering. I edited the answer. Btw, do you mean that the next image will be loaded after the current image finished loading?

Comment: Thank, I will try this out.  I understand that to check on loading I should use a script such as waitforimages, and I might, but right now I just want to make the calls to server in the correct order. :)